# vuejs infinite bounce method in component

Tags: vue.js

I have vuejs component to display image block.

Here my html, with calls 4 times the component :

```
<div id="activities" class="row text-center justify-content-center activities">
    <zpeakimage type="art" text="{{ art_text }}" img="{{asset('images/art.png')}}" target="/list/art"></zpeakimage>
    <zpeakimage type="run" text="{{ run_text }}" img="{{asset('images/run.png')}}" target="/list/run"></zpeakimage>
    <zpeakimage type="eat" text="{{ eat_text }}" img="{{asset('images/eat.png')}}" target="/list/eat"></zpeakimage>
    <zpeakimage type="party" text="{{ party_text }}" img="{{asset('images/party.png')}}" target="/list/party"></zpeakimage>
</div>
```

My vue-zpeakimage.js :

```
Vue.component('zpeakimage', {
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  props: ['type', 'text', 'img', 'target'],
  template: '<div class="col-3" style="padding-top: 20px;"><h3><a @mouseover="imgBounce(type)" :title="text" :href="target"><span> <img style="width:220px;" :id="type" :src="img" :alt="text"> </span></a></h3><span> ${text} </span></div>',
  methods: {
    imgBounce: function doBounce(Id) {
        $('#'+Id).effect('bounce', {times: 3}, 500);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#activities'
});
```

The img on mouseover bounce,  but I would like to animate up and down infinitely while the mouse is over..

Comment: You literally tell it to bounce only 3 times: `$('#'+Id).effect('bounce', {times: 3}, 500);` - change that property to whatever you need to pass into the `effect` function to make it loop it infintely. Also, this question is obviously about a third party library or about some code that has nothing to do with what you provided and therefore can't be answered in a reasonable way.

Answer (score 0):

So you want an image that bounces forever after a mouse if hovered over it. You want to do the bounce with jQuery ui.

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/273936/

```
<div id="activities" class="row text-center justify-content-center activities">
    <zpeakimage type="art" text="art_text" :img="asset('images/art.png')" target="/list/art"></zpeakimage>
    <zpeakimage type="run" text="run_text" :img="asset('images/run.png')" target="/list/run"></zpeakimage>
    <zpeakimage type="eat" text="eat_text" :img="asset('images/eat.png')" target="/list/eat"></zpeakimage>
    <zpeakimage type="party" text="party_text" :img="asset('images/party.png')" target="/list/party"></zpeakimage>
</div>

Vue.component('zpeakimage', {
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  props: ['type', 'text', 'img', 'target'],
  template: '<div class="col-3" style="padding-top: 20px;"><h3><a @mouseover="imgBounce" :title="text" :href="target"><span> <img style="width:220px;" :id="type" ref="id" :src="img" :alt="text"> </span></a></h3><span> ${text} </span></div>',
  data () {
  return {interval: null}
  },
  methods: {
    imgBounce: function () {
    if (this.interval) return
    var self = this
    this.interval = setInterval(function() {
        $(self.$refs.id).effect('bounce', {times: 3}, 500);
    } ,1000)
    }
  },
  destroyed: function() {
    if (this.interval)
        clearInterval(this.interval)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#activities'
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry, but vuejs returns errors when mouse over,  if I set ':type', ':text' ...  in HTML.  And what does means the double operator *  in javascript ?  Is it equal to  *  ?